# CRC16 calculation in c#?

Tags: c#, c++, c

i have a `c` code that i used to calculate the `crc16`, can any one convert it to c#?

```
static const unsigned short crc16tab[256]= {
0x0000,0x1021,0x2042,0x3063,0x4084,0x50a5,0x60c6,0x70e7,
0x8108,0x9129,0xa14a,0xb16b,0xc18c,0xd1ad,0xe1ce,0xf1ef,
0x1231,0x0210,0x3273,0x2252,0x52b5,0x4294,0x72f7,0x62d6,
0x9339,0x8318,0xb37b,0xa35a,0xd3bd,0xc39c,0xf3ff,0xe3de,
0x2462,0x3443,0x0420,0x1401,0x64e6,0x74c7,0x44a4,0x5485,
0xa56a,0xb54b,0x8528,0x9509,0xe5ee,0xf5cf,0xc5ac,0xd58d,
0x3653,0x2672,0x1611,0x0630,0x76d7,0x66f6,0x5695,0x46b4,
0xb75b,0xa77a,0x9719,0x8738,0xf7df,0xe7fe,0xd79d,0xc7bc,
0x48c4,0x58e5,0x6886,0x78a7,0x0840,0x1861,0x2802,0x3823,
0xc9cc,0xd9ed,0xe98e,0xf9af,0x8948,0x9969,0xa90a,0xb92b,
0x5af5,0x4ad4,0x7ab7,0x6a96,0x1a71,0x0a50,0x3a33,0x2a12,
0xdbfd,0xcbdc,0xfbbf,0xeb9e,0x9b79,0x8b58,0xbb3b,0xab1a,
0x6ca6,0x7c87,0x4ce4,0x5cc5,0x2c22,0x3c03,0x0c60,0x1c41,
0xedae,0xfd8f,0xcdec,0xddcd,0xad2a,0xbd0b,0x8d68,0x9d49,
0x7e97,0x6eb6,0x5ed5,0x4ef4,0x3e13,0x2e32,0x1e51,0x0e70,
0xff9f,0xefbe,0xdfdd,0xcffc,0xbf1b,0xaf3a,0x9f59,0x8f78,
0x9188,0x81a9,0xb1ca,0xa1eb,0xd10c,0xc12d,0xf14e,0xe16f,
0x1080,0x00a1,0x30c2,0x20e3,0x5004,0x4025,0x7046,0x6067,
0x83b9,0x9398,0xa3fb,0xb3da,0xc33d,0xd31c,0xe37f,0xf35e,
0x02b1,0x1290,0x22f3,0x32d2,0x4235,0x5214,0x6277,0x7256,
0xb5ea,0xa5cb,0x95a8,0x8589,0xf56e,0xe54f,0xd52c,0xc50d,
0x34e2,0x24c3,0x14a0,0x0481,0x7466,0x6447,0x5424,0x4405,
0xa7db,0xb7fa,0x8799,0x97b8,0xe75f,0xf77e,0xc71d,0xd73c,
0x26d3,0x36f2,0x0691,0x16b0,0x6657,0x7676,0x4615,0x5634,
0xd94c,0xc96d,0xf90e,0xe92f,0x99c8,0x89e9,0xb98a,0xa9ab,
0x5844,0x4865,0x7806,0x6827,0x18c0,0x08e1,0x3882,0x28a3,
0xcb7d,0xdb5c,0xeb3f,0xfb1e,0x8bf9,0x9bd8,0xabbb,0xbb9a,
0x4a75,0x5a54,0x6a37,0x7a16,0x0af1,0x1ad0,0x2ab3,0x3a92,
0xfd2e,0xed0f,0xdd6c,0xcd4d,0xbdaa,0xad8b,0x9de8,0x8dc9,
0x7c26,0x6c07,0x5c64,0x4c45,0x3ca2,0x2c83,0x1ce0,0x0cc1,
0xef1f,0xff3e,0xcf5d,0xdf7c,0xaf9b,0xbfba,0x8fd9,0x9ff8,
0x6e17,0x7e36,0x4e55,0x5e74,0x2e93,0x3eb2,0x0ed1,0x1ef0
}

unsigned short crc16_ccitt(unsigned char *buf, int len)
{

register int counter;
register unsigned short crc = 0;
for( counter = 0; counter < len; counter++)
    crc = (crc<<8) ^ crc16tab[((crc>>8) ^ *(char *)buf++)&0x00FF];
return crc;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And why do you want to implement it on your own in the first place? I presume some CRC implementations for C# exist already.

Comment: @Michael, i am using this one for protocol development, so the application in c# must use the same...

Comment: So just take C# and code it! It's 5 lines of code (plus constant  table)!

Comment: copy&paste, then replace the types with the corresponding C# types and fix the syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute translation from C to C# would look like this:

```
   public static class CRCHelper
   {
      private static ushort[] crc16tab = new ushort[256] {
         0x0000,0x1021,0x2042,0x3063,0x4084,0x50a5,0x60c6,0x70e7,
         0x8108,0x9129,0xa14a,0xb16b,0xc18c,0xd1ad,0xe1ce,0xf1ef,
         0x1231,0x0210,0x3273,0x2252,0x52b5,0x4294,0x72f7,0x62d6,
         0x9339,0x8318,0xb37b,0xa35a,0xd3bd,0xc39c,0xf3ff,0xe3de,
         0x2462,0x3443,0x0420,0x1401,0x64e6,0x74c7,0x44a4,0x5485,
         0xa56a,0xb54b,0x8528,0x9509,0xe5ee,0xf5cf,0xc5ac,0xd58d,
         0x3653,0x2672,0x1611,0x0630,0x76d7,0x66f6,0x5695,0x46b4,
         0xb75b,0xa77a,0x9719,0x8738,0xf7df,0xe7fe,0xd79d,0xc7bc,
         0x48c4,0x58e5,0x6886,0x78a7,0x0840,0x1861,0x2802,0x3823,
         0xc9cc,0xd9ed,0xe98e,0xf9af,0x8948,0x9969,0xa90a,0xb92b,
         0x5af5,0x4ad4,0x7ab7,0x6a96,0x1a71,0x0a50,0x3a33,0x2a12,
         0xdbfd,0xcbdc,0xfbbf,0xeb9e,0x9b79,0x8b58,0xbb3b,0xab1a,
         0x6ca6,0x7c87,0x4ce4,0x5cc5,0x2c22,0x3c03,0x0c60,0x1c41,
         0xedae,0xfd8f,0xcdec,0xddcd,0xad2a,0xbd0b,0x8d68,0x9d49,
         0x7e97,0x6eb6,0x5ed5,0x4ef4,0x3e13,0x2e32,0x1e51,0x0e70,
         0xff9f,0xefbe,0xdfdd,0xcffc,0xbf1b,0xaf3a,0x9f59,0x8f78,
         0x9188,0x81a9,0xb1ca,0xa1eb,0xd10c,0xc12d,0xf14e,0xe16f,
         0x1080,0x00a1,0x30c2,0x20e3,0x5004,0x4025,0x7046,0x6067,
         0x83b9,0x9398,0xa3fb,0xb3da,0xc33d,0xd31c,0xe37f,0xf35e,
         0x02b1,0x1290,0x22f3,0x32d2,0x4235,0x5214,0x6277,0x7256,
         0xb5ea,0xa5cb,0x95a8,0x8589,0xf56e,0xe54f,0xd52c,0xc50d,
         0x34e2,0x24c3,0x14a0,0x0481,0x7466,0x6447,0x5424,0x4405,
         0xa7db,0xb7fa,0x8799,0x97b8,0xe75f,0xf77e,0xc71d,0xd73c,
         0x26d3,0x36f2,0x0691,0x16b0,0x6657,0x7676,0x4615,0x5634,
         0xd94c,0xc96d,0xf90e,0xe92f,0x99c8,0x89e9,0xb98a,0xa9ab,
         0x5844,0x4865,0x7806,0x6827,0x18c0,0x08e1,0x3882,0x28a3,
         0xcb7d,0xdb5c,0xeb3f,0xfb1e,0x8bf9,0x9bd8,0xabbb,0xbb9a,
         0x4a75,0x5a54,0x6a37,0x7a16,0x0af1,0x1ad0,0x2ab3,0x3a92,
         0xfd2e,0xed0f,0xdd6c,0xcd4d,0xbdaa,0xad8b,0x9de8,0x8dc9,
         0x7c26,0x6c07,0x5c64,0x4c45,0x3ca2,0x2c83,0x1ce0,0x0cc1,
         0xef1f,0xff3e,0xcf5d,0xdf7c,0xaf9b,0xbfba,0x8fd9,0x9ff8,
         0x6e17,0x7e36,0x4e55,0x5e74,0x2e93,0x3eb2,0x0ed1,0x1ef0
      };

      public static ushort crc16_ccitt(byte[] buf)
      {
         ushort crc = 0;
         for (int counter = 0; counter < buf.Length; counter++)
         {
            crc = (ushort)((crc << 8) ^ crc16tab[((crc >> 8) ^ buf[counter]) & 0x00FF]);
         }
         return crc;
      }
   }
```